# Commad prompt remains open after calling a program from batchfile

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have one batch file which simply calls one program and then it remains open after program has opened. I have put exit in the last but it still remains open. If I close the program then command prompt closes automatically.
Here is the code I'm using

```
set /p device="Enter device name:"
"c:\Users\Administrator.PC1\Desktop\DCUTermFiles\%device%.DTS
exit
```

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697739/how-to-automatically-close-cmd-window-after-batch-file-execution,       I doubt same question answered here

Comment: @Jamuna .. Yeah It's the same problem.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start "" "c:\Users\Administrator.PC1\Desktop\DCUTermFiles\%device%.DTS
```

Inserting the `start` (the empty following string becomes the `start`ed application's window-title) will create an independent process, then batch will continue to `exit` without waiting for the application to close.