# Batch runs python script.. how to close cmd window at end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

I have batch file that runs python script. But, once python script finishes, cmd stays open.. How can I close it?

Thank you!

Edit: .bat script looks something like this:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:\Users\USER\Documents\Code\python\some-dir\script.py %1 %2
```

And then python script runs, and once it ends, cmd window from batch file remains open.. Can I close it somehow from python script itself or something?

Edit2: Nevermind, figured it out. You can just add `exit` at end of the batch file, and it will run once the python script ends

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] of the behavior? Both batch file and python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically close cmd window after batch file execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697739/how-to-automatically-close-cmd-window-after-batch-file-execution)

Comment: Added an example of batch script I use, it just runs a python file and passes it two variables

Comment: Is there a way to close the bat cmd file even when the python program is running? I have a python program that will run in background. I want to execute it but without showing this cmd screen. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a line with the `exit` command at the end of the batch file. That will close the cmd window when it reaches the end.

Comment: you can also use `ctrl` + `c`