# Opening project in VSCode using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, terminal, visual-studio-code

**Disclaimer:** I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697739/how-to-automatically-close-cmd-window-after-batch-file-execution) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/192550/why-wont-cmd-exit-after-execution-of-batch-file) before, but it doesn't work as I want.

**Description:** I decided to create set of batch files for convenient way to run different projects in VSCode from desktop in one click(double-click). I want close cmd terminal after running a batch file, but terminal remains. I tried:

```
start code "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory"
```

and

```
cmd /c start code "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory"
```

It quickly runs command, runs code and opens my project, then, it seems to me, closes terminal and runs a new one in desktop directory.

Comment: What is `code`? a program?

Comment: Start uses the first argument in quotes as the window title. So insert a dummy pair `start "" code "C:\Ussers\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory"` @aschipfl code is a batch in the path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`

Comment: @LotPings, I tried it, but result is the same, excepting the terminal's title. Now it is empty.

Comment: `cmd /c start "" /d "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory" code`

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you, but Code was opened with default empty project, and terminal remained opened in my project directory.

Comment: Ok. Then try `start "" cmd /c code "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory"`

Comment: @DavidPostill now it starts code in project, but empty cmd window remains without title.

Comment: Then use `start "" cmd /b code "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory"`

Comment: @DavidPostill this just open terminal at desktop directory, but I modified it a little bit, and this works excellent:
`start "" cmd /b /c code "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory" && exit 0`
Thank you, David!

Answer (score 6):

If anyone else comes across this in 2022, I found a solution that works great for me.

```
code "" "C:\path\to\folder\with\project" | exit
```

Also, below is my batch I made for a quick workspace that:

1. asks for a folder name, this will also be used as the project name
2. makes the vscode project
3. makes 2 text files, one for things I had to look up, and another for answers to my question
4. makes a png file called work.png that opens with paint for diagrams I might need for thinking through things
5. Lastly (the part I love the most) it CLOSES the command window once everything is opened!

Hope this helps someone like me who doesn't know everything about batch files!

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "folder=Enter the folder name to be created: "
md "%folder%" ||(pause &goto :eof)
cd %folder%
echo. > Things_I_had_to_look_up.txt
echo. > Answers.txt
dotnet new console
xcopy /s "C:\xPaintFileTemplate" "C:\Users\TBD\Documents\Program Work\%folder%"
start mspaint.exe Work.png
code "" "C:\Users\TBD\Documents\Program Work\%folder%" | exit
Rem not needed but to be safe
exit
```

The `C:\xPaintFileTemplate` is a folder in my C drive that contains only a png file named `Work.png`. The png file is blank, and sized to what I want mspaint to open with. If there are more files in that folder, it will copy all of them, so be careful with xcopy!

The `Rem` is a comment, saying the `exit` command doesn't seem to be required but I added it in anyways as I believe it is good practice.

Answer (score 5):

I found solution with help of [DavidPostill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536342/davidpostill). This works fine for me:

```
start "" cmd /b /c code "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory" && exit 0
```

**UPDATE:**
There is a more simple way to run VSCode using command line interface:

```sh
cd path/to/my/project
code .
```

Comment: Nothing happens if I use the `/b` switch. I don't think there is a `/b` switch if you check with `cmd /?`

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me; at worst one of the left-over CMD's needed its close button clicking three times before it would go away.

I tried the URL method and this worked just as I wanted: VSCode opened, and the cmd window went away; my batch file (`"VSCode on project.bat"`) contains just one line:

```
start vscode://file/C:/path/to/project
```

or:

```
start "" "vscode://file/C:/path/to/project"
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you try and open two VS Code instances in one batch file. A console is left hanging. For once instance it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `start cmd /C code . :0` It should be able to close the cmd terminal. At least that worked for me on my Windows 10.

Another version: 
`start cmd /C code "C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory" :0`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Blake Daugherty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689883/10043559), I found the first pair of double quotes seems unnecessary:

```
code "D:\proj\directory-1" | exit

code "D:\proj\directory-2" | exit

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

One line code:

code C:\Users\MyUserName\path\to\my\project\directory pause

Answer (score 0):

### Closing cmd window after opening VSCode with batch script

If you have the `code` command which installs with VSCode:

```
echo | code . | exit /b
```

If you're running the script as administrator:

```
cd /d %~dp0
echo | code . | exit /b
```

Using `start /b` will usually work to allow the cmd window to close for other programs.